# A palavra "cu" tem significado em todos os países que falam português?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, girias

Sei que no Brasil a palavra "cu" tem significado de "ânus" e em Portugal tem significado de "nádegas". Mas como essa palavra é interpretada nos outros países falantes da língua portuguesa?

Comment: Em Portugal *cu*  tando pode significar ’nádegas’ como ‘ânus’. O que significa que a interpretação vai depender do contexto. É ‘ânus’, por exemplo, em *meter no / ir ao / levar no / encher o cu*.

Comment: No Brasil também pode significar nádegas.